# ftp в sublime text 3

Tags: ftp, atom, sftp

Добрый день, уважаемые знатоки!

Прошу совета у всех опытных пользователей редактора Sublime Text 3.

Я в восторге от этого редактора, но столкнулся с тем что работа с удаленным сервером через встроенный FTP (SFTP) плагин крайне неудобна. Что бы открыть какой либо файл через ftp мне каждый раз приходиться идти в FILE -> SFTP/FTP -> BROWSE SERVER потом в окне которое "вывалилось" по центру, выбираю имя подключения, дальше, выбираю нужную папку, потом файл, и так каждый раз при открытии нового файла - ужасной неудобно(

Можно ли настроить ФТП таким образом что бы структура каталогов (дерево) удаленного сервера отображалась в SideBar, как например на этом скриншоте:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста возможно ли это, и если возможно как это сделать. Заранее благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: @MykolaVeriga [Пожалуйста, не отправляйте задающих вопросы в поисковики](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2013/)